# MVVM ComboBox Binding and add to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi i want to make an Binding MVVM ComboBox that i can add any name i want in the combobox from the program not source code.
I tried something but when i open the ComboBox now is showing me this.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR0eT.png)

Here is the code from the program and i don t know what is wrong, for me it's looks just fine.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace PowerTol
{
    public class Parts : Changed
    {

        public string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if(name != null)
                {
                    name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class AddViewModel : Changed
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Parts> _persons;
        public AddViewModel()
        {
            Persons = new ObservableCollection<Parts>()
             {
                  new Parts{Name="Nirav"}
                 ,new Parts{Name="Kapil"}
                 ,new Parts{Name="Arvind"}
                 ,new Parts{Name="Rajan"}
             };  
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Parts> Persons
        {
            get { return _persons; }
            set { _persons = value; }
        }
        private Parts _sperson;

        public Parts SPerson
        {
            get { return _sperson; }
            set { _sperson = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

ComboBox:

```
   <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SPersons}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="208,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="314" Height="27">

        </ComboBox>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried to reproduce your problem and I guess I found what was the point of your problem. You have to change setter of Name from

```
if (name != null)
{
   name = value;
   RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
}
```

to

```
if (name == null)
{
   name = value;
   RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
}
```

So the reason `DisplayMemberPath = "Name"` looks like it's not working because the `Name` was null after all.

Comment: Thanks it work , do you know also how can i add from a textbox to combobox ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` inside ComboBox. For now you provided objects as a source and application does not know what to show, so it displays type.